# Is there a clean way to migrate a table in SQL or PL/pgSQL while many other tables are dependent on it?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

Currently I have a table, lets call it `student` (see DDL below), that has several tables that are dependent on it. Think of tables like, `highschool_roster`, `football_roster`, `medical_records`, etc. Each row in these tables has a `student_id` that references the `student` table.

Now, the scope of the project that is using the `student` table is growing and having just a `student` table is no longer sufficient since we will now be managing high school students AND college students, so this model needs to change BUT all the data will need to remain.

In order to appease this change, a base `student` table is going to be used, and two "extension tables" are going to be used to hold data specific to that type of student. now there's going to be a `student`, `highschool_student`, and `college_student`. columns that are shared are values such as `birthday`,`identifying_gender`,`allergies` which will remain in `student`.

My question is, while maintaining data, is there a way that i can break apart the student table into a `student` and `highschool_student`, while still maintaining relationships from tables like `highschool_roster`,`football_roster`,and `medical_records`?

so my initial database setup would look something like this (PostgreSQL):

```
-- initial student model
create table student(
    student_id bigserial not null,
    birthday text not null,
    identifying_gender text not null,
    allergies text not null,
    homeroom_teacher text not null,
    allowed_off_campus boolean default false not null,
    primary key (student_id)
);
```

where the dependencies look something like (notice the foreign keys):

```
create table football_roster(
    student_id bigint not null,
    football_number bigint not null,
    position text not null,
    weight text not null,
    foreign key (student_id) references student(student_id)
);

create table nurses_office_visits(
    nurses_office_visits_id bigserial not null,
    student_id bigint not null,
    reason text not null,
    date_of_visit timestamp default now() not null,
    primary key (nurses_office_visits_id),
    foreign key (student_id) references student(student_id),
    unique (student_id, date_of_visit)
);
```

what i need my finalized DDL to look like is:

```
create table student(
    student_id bigserial not null,
    birthday text not null,
    identifying_gender text not null,
    allergies text not null,
    primary key (student_id)
);

create table highschool_student(
    student_id bigint not null,
    homeroom_teacher text not null,
    allowed_off_campus boolean default false not null,
    primary key (student_id),
    foreign key (student_id) references student(student_id)
);

create table college_student(
    student_id bigint not null,
    major text not null,
    primary key (student_id),
    foreign key (student_id) references student(student_id)
);
```

but all my data must remain intact, and relationships need to stay the same.

is there a way that i can do this in postgres or PL/pgSQL? this is just a small scale reproducible example, but in the real world there are 10-20 tables dependent on "student" so scalability should be kept in mind. my initial thought was to do a bunch of manipulation using JPA/hibernate in my code, but there must be a cleaner SQL-friendly way that i can accomplish this without creating a bunch of fake entities with fake data and inserting them into the new model.

here's some test data:

```
insert into student (student_id, birthday, identifying_gender, allergies, homeroom_teacher) values
(1, 'July 10th 1900', 'Male', 'Peanuts', 'Mr. Smith'),
(2, 'June 1st 2022', 'Female', 'N/A', 'Mrs. Smith');

insert into football_roster (student_id, football_number, position, weight) values
(1, 25, 'Quarterback', '220 lbs');

insert into nurses_office_visits (student_id, reason, date_of_visit) values
(1, 'Stomachache', now()),
(2, 'Scrape on knee', now());
```

Comment: If I understood you correct you don't actually need to change anything on the original table, just create specialized tables and link the student_id on it... all that already exists remains unchanged... and whatever new specialization will use the specialized tables. I'm not exactly sure why you think you *need* to change the existing table in order to create the specializations... The one thing you could do is to add a student_type table, and add a foreign key on student for it...

Comment: @JorgeCampos take a look at the student table in the OG DDL vs the desired student table. the OG student table has fields associated with it (homeroom_teacher, allowed_off_campus) that are not applicable to a college student. all other fields are applicable. so the specialization table for highschool student would have a student_id referencing the OG student table as well as the two columns mentioned above. `college_student` shouldn't have much an impact on "migration" since its new but the DDL is only provided to show that there are two different types of `student` that share values.

Comment: Duplicate the columns in the new tables, copy the data over, remove the columns from the original table? Your biggest problem won't be making those changes, but updating any code that reads from the columns that you're moving.

Comment: That doesn't change absolutely nothing on my statement. Yes the desired table has fewer fields but when you have a system already running you transfer the responsibility little by little. For instance in my scenario you will have the `homeroom_teacher` on the new table and in the old table UNTIL everything is migrated, then you can remove it from the original student table. The student_type ('college', 'highschool') can be added to be used as a filter so whenever you want specific college you add on your filters stundent_type = 'college' and so on...

Comment: @JorgeCampos ah. maybe this question should be closed, but thanks for the comments, they helped a lot. i was totally overthinking this and was under the assumption that since my model was changing the table needed to be gone entirely. this can be resolved with a simple `insert into highschool_student (...) select ... from student` followed by a few column drops once i've migrated.

Comment: No worries! Glad to be of any help :) .